# command to open a new tab and run a command there

Tags: bash, osx

The following repeated task need to be automated using bash script in OSx El Capitan.
open new terminal tab, go to a directory run a command on this directory to start meteor server, repeat the above 2 more times but in different directory and with slightly different commands.

The command to open run meteor is:

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017/dbname?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=dbforadmin' meteor
```

The other 2 commands append `--port=4000` and `--port=5000` to the above.

I googled for now avail. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`bash` itself doesn't know anything about tabs; that's a GUI thing.  However, you can use a tool such as `screen` to run multiple concurrent jobs.  More detail will be needed about your 'different directories' and other alterations to the iterated command, but in short:

```
$ screen -dmS Example 'sleep 30'
```

The above command will open a `screen` session as a background task called 'Example' which will execute `sleep 30` and then terminate.  You can reattach to the session to interact with or view the output of the command with `screen -x Example`.  For more information, see `man screen`.

Comment: The terminals running in different tabs are needed to view the output during app development. `~/path1/` `~/path2/` and `~/path3/` need to have the meteor server running for different apps all at the same time.